# How to find 2 integers that 'solves' a linear equation fast?

Tags: python, iteration, equation

I need a way to find integers that satisfy an equation with two unknowns. The constraints are that both integers will be between 1 and 10000. For example:

```
value = 21
for x in range(1, 10001):
    for y in range(1, 10001):
        if (3 * x) + (5 * y) == value:
            x_val = x
            y_val = y
        break
```

In this case, I would get `x_val = 2` and `y_val = 3`. **If there are no integer solutions or *multiple solutions*, then the output should be** `0`

I would like a *fast method* to solve this "equation" rather than iterating repetitively. Is this possible in python? Thank you.

Comment: What kind of equation?

Comment: @Blender It's a linear equation.

Comment: With a single equation you can't solve it without iterating.

Comment: take a look at the scipy.linalg package... it has a solver

Comment: Pyomo (or any other linear programming tool) would be easier

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(3*x)%2B(5*y)%3D21)

Comment: You can better use xrange() insted of range() this will solve it fast.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare ... um xrange will actually be slower im 99.9% sure

Comment: How come it will be because it's an generator which uses RAM to store and access element from there itself if i m wrong please correct me.

Comment: generators optimize for space not runtime ... its easy to test with timeit i think (As an aside xrange doesnt exist in py3 afaik)

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare tbh its probably not going to make much difference either way (xrange may end up being a tiny tiny bit faster in this case)

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to know that there are only POSITIVE inputs into the equation. This way you can shorten the amount of numbers that you need to check. For example if the value was 3000, you would only need to check from 1 to 1000 not from 1 to 10000. You need to divide the variable value in the equation by the lowest common denominator in the equation and use this as an upper boundary, reducing the burden of an iterative approach.

Answer (score 0):

Many solutions, here is the easiest:

```
for x in xrange(1, 10001):
    y = float(value - (x * x_val)) / y_val
    if int(y) == y and 10000 >= y >= 1:
        print ("x={}, y={}".format(int(x), int(y)))
```

Example:

```
>>> x_val = 2
>>> y_val = 3
>>> value = 21
>>> for x in xrange(1, 10001):
...     y = float(value - (x * x_val)) / y_val
...     if int(y) == y and 10000 >= y >= 1:
...         print ("x={}, y={}".format(int(x), int(y)))
... 
x=3, y=5
x=6, y=3
x=9, y=1
```

An opportunity to optimize presents itself since we don't want negative values...

```
for x in xrange(1, 10001):
    y = float(value - (x * x_val)) / y_val
    if x * x_val > value:
        break
    if int(y) == y and 10000 >= y >= 1:
        print ("x={}, y={}".format(int(x), int(y)))
```